# Why we use static block in Java? and why can't we replace it with simple statements?

Tags: java

I recently fumbled into this code:

```
  public static ArrayList<HelloGreeting> greetings = new ArrayList<HelloGreeting>();

  static {
    greetings.add(new HelloGreeting("hello world!"));
    greetings.add(new HelloGreeting("goodbye world!"));
  }
```

The question is why we use static here, can't we do just this:

```
  public static ArrayList<HelloGreeting> greetings = new ArrayList<HelloGreeting>();

    greetings.add(new HelloGreeting("hello world!"));
    greetings.add(new HelloGreeting("goodbye world!"));
```

What benefit we get, space or time?

Comment: That wouldn't compile, or where exactly would you put that code instead?

Comment: Put it inside some method and call that method or constructor .If you dont want to use static block. But then you have to create object

Comment: A good read: http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php

Comment: When you need something initialization before class loading you can do in  `static block`

Comment: It's all right here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: @Rustam - Its actually ==> *after class loading, during class initialization*

Comment: @morgano, my simple question was that what if I remove `static {}` around that code block?

Comment: @TheLostMind you are right i just missed that.

Comment: If you remove ```static {}``` you will get compile error

Comment: @user996142 - Yes, because we can't have *statements* without a block

Comment: @user996142, why? actually I am learning java so don't know much details about it.

Comment: @TheLostMind, I think initializing ArrayList is a statement too and that too without a block.

Comment: @RahulTripathi, edited the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize some data *after the class is loaded, when it is being initialized*, then you can use *static blocks*. *static blocks* are run once per class initialization (multiple times if a class is loaded and initialized by different class loaders multiple times).

Difference between static blocks and non-static blocks (your second case should be nclosed within `{..}`) is that non-static blocks will execute for each instance of `YourClass` i.e, when new instance is being constructed. Next, static blocks are thread-safe (although a class can be loaded / initialized by multiple threads)